# geometric locus formed by midpoints of chords in a circumference

Tags: geometry

Given a circumference and a point $P$ inside it, what is the locus formed by the midpoints of the chords which contain $P$? I found an awful system of parametric equations but it doesn't seem the right way... any help?

Comment: What do you mean by given a circumference? Are you given a circle? Also point $P$ inside it, what does that mean? is $P$ a point on the circle or inside the circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that midpoint of any chord is the projection of $O$ - the center of a circle onto it. So If we denote by $M$ this midpoint we can see that the angle $\sphericalangle{OMP}$ is right i.e. all such points $M$ lie on a circle with diameter $OP$.

Comment: But you didn't prove the converse: That all points on this circle are midpoints of chords through $P$.

Comment: @SRobertJames For any such point the midpoint of chord passing through it and P has P as its midpoint as it is the projection of O onto it.